# Abstract factory pattern in java

Tags: design-patterns, abstract-factory

why a certain variable is protected in the abstract factory pattern in java?
we use protected access specifier in the abstract factory pattern. so, why we use them and what is the use of the protected or private specifier in this pattern

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.